# Create exchange appointment using ews-javascript-api

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-javascript-api

On a nodejs app , I am using ews-javascript-api module to create appointments on exchange server (2013) . I've noticed the behavior that when an appointment is created , it is being shown correctly on the outlook calendar view but if I double click on the appointment and open the reply form of the appointment , the appointment's star/end times are shown on Monrovia time zone
[image]

I tried it with following code

```
const event = new ews.Appointment(service)
event.Subject = eventPayload.title
event.Start = new ews.DateTime(eventPayload.start.toString())
event.StartTimeZone =  ews.TimeZoneInfo.Local
event.End = new ews.DateTime(eventPayload.end.toString())
event.EndTimeZone =  ews.TimeZoneInfo.Local
```

and I also tried it without setting StartTimeZone/EndTimeZone but got the same issue.
I am sending the start/end dates on the utc format and the goal is to show the created appointments on outlook same as the user's timezone

any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: So what does Outlook show if you don't set the timezone? What is your local TZ?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko adding/removing event.StartTimeZone =  ews.TimeZoneInfo.Local will have the same results on outlook server. nodejs app is deployed to aws lambda where time is utc and outlook is deployed on the client's side (on-premise exchange) where TZ is UTC+1.

Comment: Then you have no choice but to explicitly set the right client-side TZ.